# Difference between fwrite and variable=fwrite

Tags: php

```
$name="Jimmy";
$open = fopen("first.txt","w");
$write = fwrite($open,$name);
```

What is the difference between this and

```
$name="Jimmy";
$open = fopen("first.txt","w");
fwrite($open,$name);
```

What does variable $write do? Why do we use it?

Comment: The variable $write would be the number of bytes written or `FALSE` if it errors out.

Comment: You can see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: But if you write just fwrite() without variable, it won't return anything?

Comment: No, it will still return it. It's just not "stored" anywhere. What I mean is, if you just do `fwrite($open, $name);`, it does return something. But you don't echo it anywhere, or anything like that so you don't necessarily know if it worked. The point of assigning the variable `$write` to the function call is so you can test against that variable to see if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

int fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )

Your variable `$write` will have: fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error.